# PHP > Pthreads detected an attempt to connect to an object which has already been destroyed

Tags: php, pthreads

```
<?php
$v = new Volatile;

$t = new class($v) extends Thread
{
   function __construct(Volatile $v)
   {
      $this->v = $v;
   }

   function run()
   {
     $this->v[] = "str";
   }
};

$t->start(); $t->join();

var_dump($v);
```

Dump:

```
object(Volatile)#1 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "str"
}
```

If I do this:

```
<?php
$v = new Volatile;

$t = new class($v) extends Thread
{
   function __construct(Volatile $v)
   {
      $this->v = $v;
   }

   function run()
   {
      $this->v[] = ["array" => ["test"]];
   }
};

$t->start(); $t->join();

var_dump($v);
```

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: pthreads detected an attempt
>   to connect to an object which has already been destroyed

How to fix this code?

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR quick Solution:**

Type cast your Array to initialize it differently in memory

```
$this->v[] = (array) ["array" => ["test"]];
```

**Working Example:**

```
class My extends Thread {
    public function run() {
        $arr = array(
            [ "foo" => "bar" ],
            [ "someInt" => 3 ],
            7       => "seven",
            "dog"   => "jack russell"           
        );
        $this->result = $arr;            // Result is Volatile object 
        $this->result = (array) $arr;    // Result is Array()
    }
}
$th = new My(); $th->start(); $th->join();
var_dump($my->result); // Array, works
```

**The Explanation:**

Your problem is due to the difficulty in sharing memory between the spawned thread and the main program.

The new thread runs with its own "private" memory allocation, away from the main program. Memory that the thread utilizes **cannot** be accessed by the parent thread. When the thread finishes the garbage collector cleans up the mess; Volatile objects are destroyed; so the data you just set isn't there any more, hence the error).

So why are you able to write it the above way **with Strings but not Arrays?** Because of the way PHP *initializes* different variable types behind the scenes!  I suspect that initializing a String (or integer) is done by PHP in the main heap and therefore can be accessed globally. Arrays are different; they are more complex reference types and initialized differently. Your statement for "str" will also work with integers if you initialize them first (see below)! Inside threads, Arrays are dealt with as Volatile objects.

Although syntactically similar, these two statements are initializing and addressing memory in different ways:

```
// What we are saying here is:
// $this->v[] points to a Volatile Object { ["array" => ["test"]] }; 

$this->v[] = ["array" => ["test"]]; // *contents* of the array is only available to the thread via Volatile {...} and only exists while the thread is running
```

*However:*

```
// What we are saying here is:
// $this->[] Should be initialized as "str" (possibly in the main heap)
$this->v[] = "str"; // *contents* of $this->v[] available to both threads and remains in memory after the thread completes
```

Similar to your "str" example, the following with Integer types will also work:

```
class My extends Thread {
    public $result = 1;
    public function run() {
        $this->result = 3; // Works
    }
}
$th = new My(); $th->start(); $th->join();
var_dump($my->result); // int(3), works
```

What you want is for the job/thread to be given the memory address of where it should dump its result as an Array class, not a Volatile. (Rather than trying to create a memory address inside the thread and giving the pointer to that address back to the parent thread, which of course will never work because the contents of that memory is wiped when the thread is done)